# AWS Javascript SDK EC2 DescribeInstances

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am trying to get date & no. of instances spin-up on that day.

Here is my code , i am beginner in development & in javascript.
so forgive me in advance for any immature code.

after getting startdate & end date , dates are stored in listDate array.
hours of a day is stored in hourArray.
then using JS SDK for AWS to get no. of instances spinned up on specific date.

ec2.describeInstances is not working as expected here ,

sometimes , i got output from ec2.describeInstances correctly , but it is always picking end date in all while loop iterations.
most of the time , ec2.describeInstances doesnt even execute.

```js
function applyFilters() {
  var listDate = [];
  demo1.innerHTML = '';
  var startDate = document.getElementById("fromdate").value;
  var endDate = document.getElementById("todate").value;
  //alert(startDate);
  //alert(endDate);
  var dateMove = new Date(startDate);
  var strDate = startDate;
  while (strDate < endDate){
     var strDate = dateMove.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    listDate.push(strDate);
     dateMove.setDate(dateMove.getDate()+1);
  };
  //alert(listDate);
  //document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "Your selected dates are";
  //demo2.innerHTML += "<br>";
  //document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = listDate;
  alert(listDate);
  var i = 0;
  var j = listDate.length;
  alert(j);
  while (i < j){
   alert(i);
   alert(listDate[i]);
   var hourArray = [];
   var d = listDate[i];
   for (var h = 0; h <= 9; h++) {
    hourArray.push(d + 'T' + '0' + h + '*');
   }
   for (var m = 10; m <= 23; m++) {
    hourArray.push(d + 'T' + m + '*');
   }
   alert(hourArray);
   var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
   AWS.config.update({
    region: "xxxxxxx",
    accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   });
   i++;
   var params = {
    Filters: [
    {
    Name: 'launch-time',
    Values: hourArray
    }]
   };
   //alert("Specified launch-times are: " + hourArray);
   ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data, d) {
    //alert(data);
    if (err) {
    //demo5.innerHTML = 'ERROR:' + err;
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var no_of_inst = data.Reservations.length;
      //demo4.innerHTML += "<br>";
      //document.getElementById('demo5').innerHTML = 'Instances migrated on' + listdate[i] + 'are: ' + no_of_inst;
      alert("Instances migrated on" + d + "are: " + no_of_inst);
    }
   });

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Migration Status</title>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">-->
<div>
 <h3> M I G R A T I O N  -  S T A T U S </h3>
</div>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.208.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Select Filters to get your ec2 graph :</p>
<form>
  <div class = "css-grid1">
   <label> Launch-time: </label>
  </div>
  <div class = "css-inlineblock1">
   <label for="fromdate">From Date:</label>
   <input type="date" id="fromdate" name="fromdate" min="2017-01-01">
   <label for="todate">To Date:</label>
   <input type="date" id="todate" name="todate">
  </div>
  <div class = "css-button">
   <input type="submit" id="sbmt" onclick="applyFilters()">
  </div>
  <div id="demo1"></div>
  <div id="demo2"></div>
  <div id="demo3"></div>
  <div id="demo4"></div>
  <div id="demo5"></div>
  <div id="demo6"></div>
  <div id="demo7"></div>
  <div id="demo8"></div>
</form>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```